# d3 collapsible search tree - remove old stokes on each search

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using [Collapsible search tree](http://bl.ocks.org/jjzieve/a743242f46321491a950). I need to remove the colored stokes of links between nodes on every new search.

How can I remove the colored stokes of link of previous search?

I tried to remove `path.link.class` that we set in the `openPaths(paths)` function in the new search. But its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this to clear the red class on each circle as shown below.

```
$("#search").on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
        var paths = searchTree(root,e.object.text,[]);
        if(typeof(paths) !== "undefined"){
          d3.selectAll("circle").style("fill", function(d) {
            d.class="";//clear the class of all circles.
            });
            openPaths(paths);
        }
        else{
            alert(e.object.text+" not found!");
        }
    })
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DsZE4tZNFT2rtlNiHXnj?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: The Collapsible Search Tree is working just for leaf nodes. Can it be possible to make it work for non-leaf nodes as well? Any help is most welcome.

Comment: This is another an enhancement should have been another SO because in this question the OP is asking something different...updated my fiddle for your requirement http://plnkr.co/edit/zWqw3eqFYD9b62XL9HNQ?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what my requirement was. And pardon me for asking an unrelated question here. Was in a hurry so didn't think much. :)